# Why implementing an Hibernate @OneToMany relationship I am obtaining this error? " Repeated column in mapping for entity: XXX.Address column: id"

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, nhibernate-mapping

I am working on a Spring Boot application using Spring Data JPA and I am finding the following problem implementing Hibernate mapping.

Basically I first created tables on my database and then I created the entity classes mapping these table (in my project the DB tables are not auto generated from the entity classes).

I have these two DB tables:

1. **portal_user**: this is the main table containing records representing the user of a portal.

   ```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.portal_user
    (
        id bigint NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807 CACHE 1 ),
        first_name character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
        middle_name character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
        surname character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
        sex "char" NOT NULL,
        birthdate date NOT NULL,
        tex_code character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
        e_mail character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
        contact_number character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
        created_at date NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT user_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
    )
   ```
2. **address**: it contais records representing the addresses of the previous users. Each user can have one or multiple adresses.

   ```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.address
    (
        id bigint NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807 CACHE 1 ),
        country character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
        province character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
        zip_code character varying(5) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
        street character varying(250) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
        notes character varying(250) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
        fk_user_id bigint NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT address_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
        CONSTRAINT fk_user_id FOREIGN KEY (fk_user_id)
            REFERENCES public.portal_user (id) MATCH SIMPLE
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            NOT VALID
    )
   ```

As you can see each user can have one or multiple adresses so the relation between **portal_user** and **address** is **ONE TO MANY** (because one user can have multiple adresses). To implement this behavior the **address** contains the **fk_user_id** field representing the ID of a specific **portal_user** record.

Ok, then I am trying to map these two tables and their relationship using Hibernate.

First I created the **User** entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "portal_user")
@Data
public class User implements Serializable {
     
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5062673109048808267L;
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;
    
    @Column(name = "middle_name")
    private String middleName;
    
    @Column(name = "surname")
    private String surname;
    
    @Column(name = "sex")
    private char sex;
    
    @Column(name = "birthdate")
    private Date birthdate;
    
    @Column(name = "tex_code")
    private String taxCode;
    
    @Column(name = "e_mail")
    private String eMail;
    
    @Column(name = "contact_number")
    private String contactNumber;
    
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "created_at")
    private Date createdAt;
    
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user", orphanRemoval = true)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<Address> addressesList = new HashSet<>();

    public User(String firstName, String middleName, String surname, char sex, Date birthdate, String taxCode,
            String eMail, String contactNumber, Date createdAt) {
        super();
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.middleName = middleName;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.sex = sex;
        this.birthdate = birthdate;
        this.taxCode = taxCode;
        this.eMail = eMail;
        this.contactNumber = contactNumber;
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }
        

}
```

As you can see this class contains all the fields defined into the **portal_user** database table and this **OneToMany** relation. Basically it says that an user is related to multiples adresses:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user", orphanRemoval = true)
@JsonManagedReference
private Set<Address> addressesList = new HashSet<>();
```

Then I created the **Address** entity class mapping my DB **address** table, this one:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "address")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor 
public class Address implements Serializable {
     
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6956974379644960088L;
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    
    @Column(name = "country")
    private String country;
    
    @Column(name = "province")
    private String province;
    
    @Column(name = "zip_code")
    private String zipCode;
    
    @Column(name = "street")
    private String street;
    
    @Column(name = "notes")
    private String notes;
    
    //@Column(name = "fk_user_id")
    //private int fkUserId;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude          // Needed by Lombock in "Many To One" relathionship to avoid error
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @JsonBackReference
    private User user;

    public Address(String country, String province, String zipCode, String street, String notes, User user) {
        super();
        this.country = country;
        this.province = province;
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
        this.street = street;
        this.notes = notes;
        this.user = user;
    }
    
}
```

As usual it contains the mapping for the **address** database table and also contains the **ManyToOne** relationship linking this class to the previous **User** class:

```
@ManyToOne
@EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude          // Needed by Lombock in "Many To One" relathionship to avoid error
@JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id")
@JsonBackReference
private User user;
```

Basically it says that multiple instance of **Address** are linked to a single specific instance of **User**.

For the sake of completeness only this is my repository interface (at the moment it is empty because I am only testing the **save()** method provided by **JpaRepository**):

```
public interface UsersRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {

}
```

Finnally I created this unit test class in order to test the insertion of a new user with the related addresses:

```
@SpringBootTest()
@ContextConfiguration(classes = GetUserWsApplication.class)
@TestMethodOrder(OrderAnnotation.class)
public class UserRepositoryTest {
    
    @Autowired
    private UsersRepository userRepository;
    
    
    @Test
    @Order(1)
    public void testInsertUser() {
        User user = new User("Mario", null, "Rossi", 'M', new Date(), "XXX", "xxx@gmail.com", "329123456", new Date());
        
        userRepository.save(user);
        
        Set<Address> addressesList = new HashSet<>();
        addressesList.add(new Address("Italy", "RM", "00100", "Via XXX 123", "near YYY", user));
        
        assertTrue(true);
        
    }
    
}
```

The problem is that running this test method I obtain the following error message in my stacktrace:

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.easydefi.users.entity.Address column: id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:421) ~[spring-orm-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    ... 84 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.easydefi.users.entity.Address column: id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:862) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkPropertyColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:880) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:902) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:634) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:267) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.validate(MetadataImpl.java:354) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:298) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:468) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1259) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    ... 88 common frames omitted
```

Why this error? What am I missing? How can I try to solve this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's your double mapping

```
@ManyToOne
@EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude          // Needed by Lombock in "Many To One" relathionship to avoid error
@JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id")
private User user;
```

Should be:

```
@ManyToOne
@EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude          // Needed by Lombock in "Many To One" relathionship to avoid error
@JoinColumn(name = "fk_user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
private User user;
```

You are mapping the `id` twice (first appearance is the `@Id` column name), the foreign key column should be `fk_user_id` according to your DDL.

Comment: and what have I to do to solve my issue? what have I to remove?

Comment: It should be `@JoinColumn(name = "fk_user_id"` instead of `@JoinColumn(name = "id"`

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have mapped the same column twice in Address

```
 @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude          // Needed by Lombock in "Many To One" relathionship to avoid error
 @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id")
 @JsonBackReference
 private User user;
```

and

```
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
```

You probably wanted to say user_id in the first one but cannot be sure as I think you pasted the same SQL for table creation twice instead of the address one. 
Edit:
try using user_id instead of id in mapping of User user in Address and error should be gone.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my original post inserting the correct SQL for the "address" table